# Access content database using sharepoint web services

Tags: web-services, sharepoint

Is there any way to access the name of content database using sharepoint web services? Also can we get list of all the web applications in a sharepoint farm by any way?

Basically we can do a lot with Server based object model ( Microsoft.Sharepoint.dll). Can't we do all those things with web services?

Comment: Why not use client object model? Is it MOSS 2007 or 2010?

Comment: Thanks Shoban. Being very new to it I was not knowing much about it. Let me download it and see if it fulfills my requirement. Thanks again.

Comment: Is it 2007 or 2010 version? 2007 version does not have Client Object Model.

Comment: 2010. I got the object model from MSDN. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got to know about the Client Object Model 2010. Still could not access the name of content database for a particular site.

I think such facility is available only in server object model.